# jw player conflicting with SDL Tridion SiteEdit

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

None of my jw player video files are playing when used on site having SDL Tridion SiteEdit enabled. Is there any solution to this problem?

I am using jw player js version - 5.6.1792.

This is the code I have added which is replaced by some object at run time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

jwplayer("_ei_Lewis_Thomas_SocialImpact_hi_flv1378355799").setup({
'width': "458",
'height': "284",
'allowscriptaccess': 'always',
'allownetworking': 'all',
'provider': 'rtmp',
'streamer': "rtmp://cp55519.edgefcs.net/ondemand/flash",
'controlbar': 'bottom',
'primary': 'flash',
'icons': 'true',
'stretching': 'exactfit',
'skin': "/images/jwplayerskin.zip",

'modes': [
{
type: 'html5',
config: {
'file': '',
'provider': 'video'
}
},
{
type: 'download',
config: {
'file': '',
'provider': 'video'
}
},
{type: 'flash', src: '/images/jwplayer.swf',
config : {
'autostart': 'true',
'levels': [
               { 'bitrate': "500", 'file': "/ei/Lewis_Thomas_SocialImpact_lo.flv" },
                { 'bitrate': "1500", 'file': "/ei/Lewis_Thomas_SocialImpact_hi.flv" }
        ]
}
},
],
'plugins': {
'gapro-2': {}
}  
});  

});  
</script>
```

I get an error after page is loaded

> object expected

But it comes in some line of  jwplayer.js, which is minified. So I just can't figure out why it's there.

And yes there are span tags added by SiteEdit, but there is no way I can do away with those tags.

Tridion UI- 2012.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide a bit more details, like what is mentioned in the console of your browser (are there any errors) and what snippet do you use to embed your jw player videos?

Comment: Also which version of Site Edit and Tridion is this?

Comment: when you manually create a webpage with this player code in it, does that work for you? Or might there be something wrong with the player `.swf`, `.zip` and `.flv` files?

Comment: Don't think so. In one of the environments, where site-edit is disabled, the same code does wonders.

Comment: That indeed sounds like a javascript conflict, would be worth a try loading the jwplayer script after the siteedit bootstrap script and see if the video works (could mean XPM won't work anymore then).

Answer (score 4):

SiteEdit will change the HTML document a bit by adding `<span>` tags. These tags might mess up the player. The solution would be to change the template in Tridion to make sure the fields used by the player are not maked up with `<span>` tags, but that depends on what the actual problem is, what is rendered by the template and how the jw player works. Could you check in the browser why the video files are not loading?

Comment: It just shows a blank place holder instead of video. Can't figure out why, that's why have posted it here.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to dive into the uncompressed version of  jwplayer.js to debug and see what goes on.